# TYPO3 Redirect to pid if user is logged in

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-9.x

The given scenario is a login page and another page with a user restriction.

[image: Page structure]

What is the best practice to redirect the user automatically to the restricted page if he calls the login page but is already logged in?
The workflow should be:

- User calls Login-page
- TYPO3 detects that the user is already logged in
- TYPO3 redirects the user to Restricted-page

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this extension : https://bitbucket.org/ideativedigital/t3-redirect40x/src/master/. I know it works with TYPO3 9 but you will probably need some adjustements if you need it to work with TYPO3 8.

Answer (score 0):

In Typoscript you can use conditions to a) check if a user is logged in and b) check what page they are on. Then you can add some addtional headers to do the forwarding.

```
[usergroup = *] && [globalVar = TSFE:id = YOUR-LOGIN-ID]
config.additionalHeaders.cObject = COA
config.additionalHeaders.cObject {
    10 = TEXT 
    10.value = HTTP/1.0 302 Temporary Redirect | Location: http://www.your-domain.com
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
      typolink.parameter = YOUR-FORWARDING-ID
      typolink.returnLast = url
    }
}
[global]
```

usergroup can be * = all usergroups or you can put the actual ID of the usergroup(s) you want to forward. YOUR-LOGIN-ID should be the pid of the page where your login is. YOUR-FORWARDING-ID should be the id of the page you want to forward to

Comment: Thats the solution I currently use for this problem.

`[globalVar = TSFE:id = {$page.theme.countrySpecificRoot} ] && [loginUser = *]
    config >
    config.additionalHeaders = TEXT
    config.additionalHeaders {
        10 {
            header = Location: {$page.theme.countrySpecificHomeURL}
        }
        20.header = Cache-control: Private
    }
[end]`

But with this solution I cannot specify the page to redirect by a page uid.

Comment: if all you want is the id you could just make the additionalheader forward to www.mydomain.com/index.php?id=YOUR-ID. However that wont give you a pretty URL but maybe thats not important? If it is important you can also build a typolink first, put it in the register and then wrap your additionalheader around it. I edited my anwer to incorporate this (untested but should work)